# Cocoa, binding using Collection Operators and To-Many relationship properties

Tags: cocoa, core-data, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings

Having done a fair amount of google and looking on here I believe the following can't be done. I'm interesting in why it can't be done and people best workarounds, I offer mine below.

I use the simple department <---->> employee model, with both having a name attribute and the employee entity also having a timeWorked attribute.

**The Problem**

I would like to bind up a table with column one displaying departement.name and column two displaying department.@sum.employees.timeWorked. Attempting to do this results in the error:

```
[<_NSFaultingMutableSet 0x1d5e50> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: timeWorked
Cannot remove an observer <NSTableBinder 0x1a9280> for the key path "employees.timeWorked" from <Depatement 0x1faf40> because it is not registered as an observer.
```

However a bind to department.employees.@count does work (but I want more!).

**Other Discussions**

Here's another topic here with the same problem: [nstablecolumn-binding-using-collection-operators-like-sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517145/nstablecolumn-binding-using-collection-operators-like-sum)

And another: [cocoa-bindings-binding-to-the-many-end-of-a-to-many-relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826009/cocoa-bindings-binding-to-the-many-end-of-a-to-many-relationship)

**My Workaround**

My solution to this problem is to create an attribute for the Department Entity which performs the sum:

```
-(NSNumber *)departmentHours {  
    return [self valueForKeyPath:@"employees.@sum.timeWorked"]; }
```

and to then simply bind to it.

It's only a little more code at add these attributes when I want to do some sort of collation / aggregation of data but I do feel it would be more elegant to be able to bind to 
 department.@sum.employees.timeWorked.

Any Ideas?? Reasons why it doesn't work? Better workarounds?

Cheers All

Comment: is it necessary to create an attribute or a category with the above method.

Comment: Doesn't have to be an attribute and saved in the persistent store.  You can just have it be an @property on the department class.  Changing any employee's timeWorked will not necessarily lead to a recalculation of departmentHours, though.  Unless the employee's setTimeWorked changes a keyPath in keyPathsForValuesAffectingDepartmentHours

Answer (score 0):

You write about binding to `department.@sum.employees.timeWorked` - however, I think you should be binding to `department.employees.@sum.timeWorked`